# SQL query resultset is case insensitive

Tags: c#, sql

Beside the style of these few lines that I will sort out later, why this check is resulting to be case insensitive?

```
conn.Open();
string checkUser = "Select count(*) from Tb_Registration Where Username= '" + txtUser.Text + "'";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkUser, conn);
int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Trim());
conn.Close();
```

In the DB I have "User1" in a `varchar` column but still the value of temp is 1 if I check "USER1" or "user1".If I check for "user" it is 0.

Comment: Apparently, you can use `COLLATE` to force sensitivity.;

Comment: Do you have a record with the username `user`? The sensitivity of the cases searched depends on the collation of the column you're searching.

Comment: @DrewKennedy for testing purposes I have a "user". Have not set any collation at DB level.

Comment: AFAIK T-SQL is generally not case sensitive. "User1" = "USER1" = "user1" unless otherwise specified.

Comment: You could try using "LIKE" rather than "="

Comment: Use prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

Check your collation.  Any binary collation WILL BE case sensitive.  Latin General Bin is an example.  You can always call ToLower() or ToUpper() if you need to match case.